# Why Python voice assistant works so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, voice-recognition, python-3.12

I am making a voice assistant using Python 3.12 on MacOS. Now, i am at voice recognition step, but it needs like 6 seconds for just recognize my speech and say 'How can i help you' to user. I know, that would be better to use pydub for silence detection, but now i have **the newest Python version**, and about 90% of libraries currently don't support my Python version, and because of that, i made silence detection **from scratch** using NumPy and SciPy. It should be noted, that  most of libraries that can help making voice assistant, don't support MacOS (i use MacOS Monterey).
Should i optimize my code by removing class `AudioRecorder` and switching to older, but more popular version, and continue working in Python 3.10, for example, or should i rewrite code in more effective way, or my hardware just can't normally handle this program? Here are my specifications:

```
OS: macOS 12.6.6 21G646 x86_64 
Host: MacBookPro 12,1 
Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
CPU: Intel i5-5287U (4) @ 2.90GHz 
GPU: Intel Iris Graphics 6100 
Memory: 16384MiB
```

Also, here is my code:

```
import vosk
import json
from pyaudio import *
import numpy as np
import time
import gtts
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


class AudioRecorder():
    def __init__(self, max_silence_duration=1500, sample_rate=16000, chunk_size=1024,       
                 silence_thresh=1000):
        self.max_silence_duration = max_silence_duration
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.silence_thresh = silence_thresh
        self._frames = b''
        self._start_time = None
        self.stream = None
        self.p = None

    def add_data_to_frames(self, new_data):
        self._frames += new_data

    def is_silence(self, audio_chunk, silence_thresh=-300, energy_thresh=1):
        energy = np.sum(audio_chunk.astype(np.float32)
                        ** 2) / float(len(audio_chunk))
        return energy < energy_thresh or np.max(np.abs(audio_chunk)) < silence_thresh

    def record_audio(self, max_silence_duration=1500, sample_rate=16000, chunk_size=1024, silence_thresh=1000):
        self.p = PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=paInt16,
                                  channels=1,
                                  rate=sample_rate,
                                  input=True,
                                  frames_per_buffer=chunk_size)

        self._frames = b''
        self._start_time = time.time()

        print("Recording...")

        try:
            while True:
                data = self.stream.read(chunk_size)
                audio_chunk = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)

                self.add_data_to_frames(new_data=data)

                if not self.is_silence(audio_chunk, silence_thresh=silence_thresh):
                    self._start_time = time.time()
                elif time.time() - self._start_time >= max_silence_duration / 1000.0:
                    break

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Recording interrupted.")

        finally:
            print("Recording finished.")
            if self.stream and self.stream.is_active():
                self.stream.stop_stream()
                self.stream.close()
                print("Audiorecognizer.stream closed.")

            if self.p:
                self.p.terminate()
                print("PyAudio terminated.")

        return self._frames, self.p, self.stream

    def recognize_speech(self, audio_data):
        path_to_model = "/Users/dimapogarskiy/vosk-model-en-us-0.22-lgraph"
        model = vosk.Model(path_to_model)
        recognizer = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
        recognizer.AcceptWaveform(audio_data)

        result = json.loads(recognizer.Result())
        recognized_text = result.get('text', '')

        return recognized_text


def speak(text: str):
    tts = gtts.gTTS(text, lang='en')
    tts.save('hello.wav')
    song = AudioSegment.from_file("hello.wav")

    return play(song)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    recognizer = AudioRecorder()

    try:
        speak('How can I help you?')
        audio_recorder_data, p, stream = recognizer.record_audio()
        recognized_text = recognizer.recognize_speech(
            audio_data=audio_recorder_data)
        print("Recognized text:", recognized_text)


        if 'hello' in recognized_text or 'hi' in recognized_text:
            speak('Hello sir')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program interrupted. Cleaning up...")

    finally:
        if 'stream' in locals() and recognizer.stream is not None and 
            recognizer.stream.is_active():

            recognizer.stream.stop_stream()
            recognizer.stream.close()
            print("Audio stream closed.")

        if 'p' in locals():
            recognizer.p.terminate()
            print("PyAudio terminated.").
```

I tried using pydub and librosa for silence detection, but only making it fro scratch was a good idea. The problem is, that this method loads the CPU much more than other libraries.
Please, help me.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler to determine where your program spends most of its time?